# How to create dynamic HTML tags with razor actionlink in c# ViewData string

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a dynamic menu depending on the user role in MVC C#, and (while I can load the HTML tags) the Action links in the menu are not rendering. I imagine this is due to the @ at sign at the beginning:

```
if(userGroup.Equals("Administrators")){
   menuItems+=@"<span class=""menuItem"">
                      @Html.ActionLink(""Add User"", ""RegisterNewUser"", ""Home"", null, new{@Class=""menuItemActionLink""})
                      </span>";
}
(...)
ViewData["menuItems"]=menuItems;
```

With a view retrieval:

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewData["menuItems"])
```

I have attempted variations of html encoding to no avail. The best solution I can think of is to use the at sign escape code, but I do not know what it is (I tried '\' as well as concatenation in the form of "@" + @"Html.ActionLink). Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you do it inside view?

Comment: The mixing of view and controller code isn't the right way.

Comment: Have you tried with two @.. ex: `@@Html.ActionLink...`?

Comment: Ehsan I cannot access the userGroup data in the view, and can't put ViewData inside a razor if (that I know of)

Shoe I know, but I know of no other way (tips more than welcome)

DJ Yes, just did, no go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not sure why exactly it is that the actionlink is not being rendered properly (maybe the upper-case C in class?), the practice of sending html from the controller to the view is not a good idea. This conflates the roles of controller and view, and makes it more difficult for anyone expecting the distinction between these entities.

A better option might be to have a code block in the view such as:

```
@if (ViewData["admin"] != null){  ...code to render your admin menu ... }
```

and in your controller:

```
if(userGroup.Equals("Administrators")){ ViewData["admin"] = true; }
```

Depending on your needs, these snippets may change. You could test for true or false (instead of null), or add a string; the ViewData is pretty much what you make of it. But this at least maintains the distinction between HTML rendering at the View and process control at the controller.

Comment: Sukotto1, you are awesome, I am fairly new to MVC, and I didn't know how to access ViewData from within an inline razor statement. I tried accessing the class data directly, adding an App_Code folder, even creating an *eek* global class. You're the man

Comment: Haha, I've been there. I'm pretty new myself. It's a powerful thing when you get used to it. But ViewData and ViewBag definitely have their downsides too. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(userGroup.Equals("Administrators")) {
    menuItems += "<span class=\"menuItem\">" + Html.ActionLink("Add User", "RegisterNewUser", "Home", null, new { @class = "menuItemActionLink" }) + "</span>";
}
```